# How to avoid alphabet and special characters in a UITextfield?

Tags: ios

I am formatting a US mobile number in a UITextfield.
I was done displaying the US number format, but it allows alphabet and special characters, including symbols.

I don't want allow alphabet and special characters.
How can I avoid these unwanted characters?

Please give any examples.

Comment: set keyboard type is UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad.

Comment: already changed uikeyboardTypeNumberPad, it working , but o not allowed after starting uitextfield

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed irrelevant thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#define ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS @" Replace with what you want to be allowed."

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:  (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {
  NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS] invertedSet];

  NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

  return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
```

}

Comment: my requirement is textfield starting postion,its allow only 1 to 9 numbers not allow 0. i was fixed this issue. but its not allow zero entiry text field

Comment: 1-222-222-2222. it allows, but i will give 1-220-222-2222 it not allowd zero

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link which fulfills your requirement of displaying and accepting only numeric values in UITextFiled -

http://hugolarcher.com/uitextfield-allowing-only-decimal-characters/